# "Object is possibly 'null'" error message when non-null value guaranteed

Tags: typescript

In the below code, class field `$LoadingMessage` is nullable, however it will be initialized in the constructor.

```
export default class ImageFullScreenViewer {

  private static readonly LOADING_MESSAGE_CSS_SELECTOR_BY_ID: string = '#ImageFullScreenViewer-LoadingMessage';
  private $LoadingMessage: JQuery | null = null;

  constructor (thumbnailsContainerSelectors: string | Array<string>, adaptedPageLayoutManager: AdaptedPageLayoutManager) {
    this.$LoadingMessage = $(ImageFullScreenViewer.LOADING_MESSAGE_CSS_SELECTOR_BY_ID);
  }

  showLoadingMessage() {
    this.$LoadingMessage.show(); //  Object is possibly 'null'.
  }
}
```

In strict mode, TypeScript tells me that `Object is possibly 'null'` in the `showLoadingMessage` method. `showLoadingMessage` is non-static method, so it could not be called without `ImageFullScreenViewer` instance creation. As far as I know, jQuery function does not return null, so initialization with non-null value is guaranteed.

Is "TypeScript message Object is possibly 'null' is unreasonable in this case" conclusion right? (I want to crate an issue in GitHub, but TODO list before issue that they requires is too bothersome ...)

Comment: `$LoadingMessage` is the object that can be null, not `this`.

Comment: Why did you use the type `JQuery | null` to represent a non-nullable value?

Comment: @JBNizet, well, because I don't know other ways. Please teach me.

Comment: @Silvermind, I suppose thanks to `@types/jquery`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is working as intended.  As JB Nizet suggested, the error is based on the declared type of `$LoadingMessage`, which is `JQuery | null`.  While the compiler has a "narrowing" feature that will try to determine a more specific type for a variable based on recent assignments, narrowing does not work across functions.

So if you want code to be able to assume that `$LoadingMessage` is non-null, you should declare the type as `JQuery` and remove the `= null` initializer; then the compiler will enforce that you assign a non-null value in the constructor.  (Of course, there is a brief window before the assignment in the constructor during which `$LoadingMessage` is actually undefined, despite its type; this is one of the many scenarios in which TypeScript has traded off soundness for ease of use.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I see, type checking engine cannot recognize is `$LoadingMessage` is class field or not, can it? If I declare type as `JQuery` and JQuery will not found element `#ImageFullScreenViewer-LoadingMessage`, empty JQuery object will be returned and there will not be the error like `element not found`. It could take a lot of time during debugging...

Comment: I don't understand your first question at all.  If jQuery doesn't find the `#ImageFullScreenViewer-LoadingMessage` element, it will return an empty (but non-null) jQuery object regardless of the type you declare for `$LoadingMessage`, so the need to check for that case to avoid difficult debugging is an unrelated issue.